# Including console.info

Tags: php, javascript

I work with a contractor developer who insisted on modifying one of the existing files by placing the following two lines of code into a file (#1 below), included at the beginning of my code:

```
function _info($Object){echo '<script type="text/javascript">console.info("'.$Object.'");</script>';}
function _infoJS($Object){echo 'console.info("'.$Object.'");';}
```

My file includes are something like this:

```
<application>
    <included file #1>

    if A
       <include project A>
    else 
       <include project B>

</application>
```

The problem is that this include file is used by other applications and I can not modify it. Does the `console.info` have to be included at the very beginning? I can easily include it in the header (between `<head></head>` or even before) of `<include project A>` or  `<include project B>`.

Comment: What did the contractor hope to gain with this? Looks like debugging information that should not be left in production code anyway. If the functions `_info()` and `_infoJS()` are not called elsewhere in your script, they're basically harmless, but I fail to see why they're needed.

Comment: What is the question here? console.info is browser debugging code [if the browser has it.] It should not be in production code and will throw errors for browsers that do not support it or do not have it enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can include this file anywhere before the functions `_info()` or `_infoJS()` are called in your code.  It doesn't have to be at the very beginning if the functions defined in it are not being called immediately.

However, I would probably search the rest of the codebase for calls to those functions, and unless you really need the additional debugging information in your *development* code, remove them.  These should likely not be present in production code if the purpose of these functions is what it appears to be.

In case it isn't clear what these functions do, they write to the output HTML a call to the JavaScript `console.info()` function, passing it whatever object is passed in the variable `$Object`. That bit of information is simply printed to the JavaScript console, if it is available, and would throw errors if not available.

Comment: This is very useful. I'll try to find out what the code was really used for. Thanks.